# Getting error while loading component dynamically on chaning model

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using following snippet of code to generate the component dynamically. Along with the dynamic component I am passing data also which I am binding to the html element on dynamically generated component.

```
const hostViewContainerRef = this.Host.viewContainerRef;
let compFactory = this.componentfacResolve.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
const compRef = hostViewContainerRef.createComponent(compFactory );
compRef.instance.DataOrig = _.cloneDeep(this.myData);
```

And I am using @input attribute to collect the data at generated component

```
@Input()
public DataOrig : MyModel;
```

Upto this point everything is working fine, it is rendering the component and also passing the data. But if I tried to changed value on "DataOrig" like

```
DataOrig.firstname = "Changed First Name"
```

I am getting error "Cannot add property firstname , object is not extensible" and for some other fields I am getting "Cannot assign to read only property 'other fields' of object "

But Instead of the dynamic component if I use other static component tag then everything works fine. Do I need to give some special treatment for Dynamically generated component?